# Compress/zips folder while excluding specific folders

Tags: powershell, zip, compression, 7zip

I am trying to find a way to compress/zip folders in a file-share.

There are some folders that need to be omitted. However all the folders that I need compressed have names that are 29 characters long.

I was looking into both using a bat file or a powershell script. Also was looking into using 7zip.

Any suggestions or help would be great.

Comment: How would you identify the files that need to be excluded?

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell 5.0 there is a new module called: Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive

From there you can use [Compress-Archive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive) and [Expand-Archive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive) to easily generate .zip files.